# How to make use of a reduction formula for the integral $I_n= \int \frac{d x}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}},$ where $k\geq 2 \textrm{ and }n\in N$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals, reduction-formula

We are going to find the reduction formula by differentiation. $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d x}\left[\frac{x}{k n\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}}\right] &=\frac{1}{k n} \frac{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n} \cdot 1-x n\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n-1} \cdot k x^{k-1}}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{2 n}} \\
&=\frac{1}{k n} \cdot \frac{x^{k}+1-k n\left(x^{k}+1-1\right)}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n+1}} \\
&=\frac{1-k n}{k n\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}}+\frac{1}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n+1}}
\end{aligned}$$

Integrating both sides yields $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x}{kn\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}} &=\frac{1-k n}{k n} \int \frac{d x}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}}+\int \frac{d x}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n+1}} \\
I_{n+1} &=\frac{x}{kn\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}}+\frac{k n-1}{k n} I_{n} .
\end{aligned}
$$

Furthermore, when we consider the integral with limits $0$ and $\infty$,we got a wonderful closed form for the integral $$
J_{n}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}}
$$

Applying the reduction formula of $I_n$ with the limits yields $$
\begin{aligned}
J_{n+1} &=\frac{k n-1}{k n} J_{n} \\
& \qquad\qquad \vdots \\
&=\frac{(k n-1)[k(n-1)-1] \ldots(k\cdot 1-1)}{k^{n} n !} J_{1} \\
&=\displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(kj-1\right)}{k^{n} n !} J_{1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the [result](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-prove-that-displaystyle-int_0-infty-dfrac-dx-1-x-n-dfrac-pi-n-cdot-dfrac-1-sin-dfrac-pi-n/answer/Frank-Wei-19?ch=17&oid=90085554&share=a978c1e2&srid=CCOmo&target_type=answer),
$$
J_{1}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x^{k}+1}=\frac{\pi}{k} \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)
$$

Now we can conclude that $$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}}=\frac{\pi \displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(k j-1)}{k^{n}(n-1) !} \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)}
$$

Comment: By the way, (+1) again for another interestin post. My answer is a personal comment from an old man to a brilliant  user. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Following your interesting posts for a while, in my humble opinion, it is probably time for you to start using hypergeometric functions or at least the simplest one (the gaussian hypergeometric function).

Using them, you would have
$$I_n= \int \frac{d x}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}}=x \,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{k},n;\frac{k+1}{k};-x^k\right)$$
$$J_n= \int_0^\infty \frac{d x}{\left(x^{k}+1\right)^{n}}=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) \Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{1}{k}\right)}{\Gamma (n)}$$ which is valid if $\Re(k n)>1\land \Re(k)>0$.

For sure, what you wrote for $J_n$ is the same. With regard to the reduction formula for $I_n$, you will find a lot of them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I should start learning about hypergeometric functions.